# How to use sed to isolate only the first part of a file

Tags: sed, gnu

I'm running Windows and have the GnuWin32 toolkit, which includes sed.  Specifically:

C:\TEMP>sed --version

GNU sed version 4.2.1

I have a text file with two sections:  A fixed part I want to preserve, and a part that's appended after running a job.

In the file is a unique string that identifies the start of the part that's added, and I'd like to use Gnu sed to isolate only the part of the file that's before the unique string - i.e., so I can append different data to the fixed part each time the job is run.

I know I could keep the fixed portion in a separate file, but that adds complexity and it would be more elegant if I could just reuse the data at the start of the same file.

A long time ago I knew how to set up sed scripts, and I'm sure this can be done with sed, but I've slept since then.  :)

Can you please describe how to use sed to display the lines of text in a file up to and not including a specific string?

Example:

```
line 1 of fixed portion
line 2 of fixed portion
unique string
line 1 of appended portion
line 2 of appended portion
line 3 of appended portion
```

What I'd like is to see as output:

```
line 1 of fixed portion
line 2 of fixed portion
```

I've gotten as far as:

```
sed -r -n -e "0,/unique string/p"
```

but that prints the unique string as well.

Thanks in advance.

-Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
sed -n '/unique string/q;p' file
```

It quits processing at `unique string`. Other lines get printed.

An alternative might be to use a range address like this:

```
sed -n '1,/unique string/{/unique string/!p}' file
```

Note that `sed` includes the range border. We need to exclude `unique string` from printing.

Furthermore I'm using the `-n` option which makes `sed` suppress the output of input lines by default.

---

One thing, if `unique string` can contain characters which are also syntax characters in the regex like ...

```
test*
```

... `sed` might not be the right tool for the job any more since it can only match regular expressions but not *fixed strings*.

In that case `awk` might be the tool of choice:

```
awk 'index("*unique string*"){exit}1' file
```

`index("string")` returns a non zero value (the position) if the string has been found. We cancel further processing of input lines in that case and don't print that line as well.

The trailing `1` always evaluates to true and makes `awk` print all the lines until the previous condition applies.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Simple and straightforward, with two choices.  I'll choose this as the answer as soon as the system lets me.

Comment: Sed seems perfectly happy to match characters that are used in regular expressions as long as they're escaped.

In any case I have control of what's in the unique string.

Comment: Sure, as long as you have control you can escape special regex characters or you can even take advantage out of the fact that you can pass a regex.